# Why do some Muslim Scholars require a woman to have permission to leave the country?

Tags: women

I heard about one woman who convinced her family to go to Austria on a vacation but then left to go to Sweden. This woman was a Muslim woman from Saudi Arabia and tried to leave but needed the permission of a male. Does this go in accordance with what Islam says or is this kind of thing not right? Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: The permission thing depends on the tradition of the locality. Like here in India non-muslims also seek permission of gaurdian (male/female) if they want to go somewhere of stay late in friend's house

Answer (score 1):

the prophet warned us that a women can not travel the distance of a one days travel without a mahram (man she cannot marry such as brother father uncle husband etc)

> Sayyiduna Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased with him) narrates that the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) said: “It is unlawful for a woman who believes in Allah and the last day that she travels the distance of one day and one night without a Mahram accompanying her.” (Sahih al-Bukhari, no. 1038)

so not only does she need permission, she needs somone to accompany her too. the reason for this is because there may be danger in travelling alone. but if the distance is close enough she may go alone such as a supermarket or store.